# sorting array via ksort is not working, running ksort on array outputs "1"

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
[16-Sep-2019 11:55:54 UTC] Array
(
    [28-09-2019] => <option value="10214" >28-09-2019 | Bernina borduurdag (voormiddag)</option>
    [07-12-2019] => <option value="10216" >07-12-2019 | Bernina academie</option>
    [25-10-2019] => <option value="10212" >25-10-2019 | Workshop kennismaking overlockmachine (voormiddag)</option>
    [21-12-2019] => <option value="10202" >21-12-2019 | Les Overlock (alle merken)</option>
    [11-10-2019] => <option value="10203" >11-10-2019 | Demonstratie naaivoeten Brother</option>
    [06-09-2019] => <option value="10054" >06-09-2019 | Les Overlock (alle merken)</option>
    [20-12-2019] => <option value="10185" >20-12-2019 | Les Brother</option>
    [13-12-2019] => <option value="10195" >13-12-2019 | Les Pfaff</option>
    [30-11-2019] => <option value="10175" >30-11-2019 | Les Borduurmachines (alle merken)</option>
    [09-11-2019] => <option value="10182" >09-11-2019 | Les Brother</option>
    [26-10-2019] => <option value="10189" >26-10-2019 | Les Bernina</option>
    [05-10-2019] => <option value="10188" >05-10-2019 | Les Bernina</option>
    [27-09-2019] => <option value="10062" >27-09-2019 | Les Bernina</option>
    [08-11-2019] => <option value="10173" >08-11-2019 | Les Coverlock (alle merken)</option>
    [12-10-2019] => <option value="10181" >12-10-2019 | Les Brother</option>
    [28-12-2019] => <option value="10174" >28-12-2019 | Les Coverlock (alle merken)</option>
    [14-12-2019] => <option value="10184" >14-12-2019 | Les Brother</option>
    [29-11-2019] => <option value="10183" >29-11-2019 | Les Brother</option>
    [20-09-2019] => <option value="10187" >20-09-2019 | Les Bernina</option>
    [27-12-2019] => <option value="10176" >27-12-2019 | Les Borduurmachines (alle merken)</option>
    [04-10-2019] => <option value="10058" >04-10-2019 | Les Borduurmachines (alle merken)</option>
    [23-11-2019] => <option value="10179" >23-11-2019 | Les ScanNCut</option>
    [14-09-2019] => <option value="10177" >14-09-2019 | Les ScanNCut</option>
    [13-09-2019] => <option value="10171" >13-09-2019 | Les Coverlock (alle merken)</option>
    [07-09-2019] => <option value="10060" >07-09-2019 | Les Pfaff</option>
    [21-09-2019] => <option value="10052" >21-09-2019 | Les Overlock (alle merken)</option>
    [31-08-2019] => <option value="10056" >31-08-2019 | Les Overlock (alle merken)</option>
    [11-09-2019] => <option value="10048" >11-09-2019 | Workshop kennismaking overlockmachine (namiddag)</option>
    [18-09-2019] => <option value="10046" >18-09-2019 | Workshop PE Design plus 2</option>
    [25-09-2019] => <option value="10042" >25-09-2019 | Workshop boodschappentas (namiddag)</option>
    [23-10-2019] => <option value="10040" >23-10-2019 | Workshop Pfaff Performance Icon</option>
)
```

I've tried using all sorts of sorts. I found some answers on stackoverflow which provided usort with a custom callback, but I think this should be possible with ksort.

This piece of code constructs the array

```
 $eventList = [];

        foreach($events as $event)  {
            $origDate = $event->mec_start_date;

            $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($origDate));

            $eventList[$newDate] = '<option value="' . $event->ID . '" ' . ($mec_event_id == $event->ID ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $newDate . ' | ' . $event->post_title .  '</option>';
        }
```

When I do a write_log()

```
write_log(ksort($eventList));
```

I get the following result in the debug.log

```
[16-Sep-2019 11:55:54 UTC] 1
```

I've also tried using the `$origDate` as a key, but this also outputs `"1"`

I want to sort the array keys so that the first date is first and so forth.

I don't have a clue why it just outputs `"1"`. I just wrapped `ksort()` around the `$eventList`

Comment: Don't reassign when calling ksort, it works inline

Comment: Although duplicate is talking about `sort()` the reason is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns 1 because as per [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

> **Note:-** Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Proper way of doing is,

```
ksort($eventList); // will sort internally. No need to catch in some variable
write_log($eventList);
```

Comment: This. Exactly, I had no idea that it worked inline like this. I also read that doc, but never saw the light that I was getting the return value, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will in 9 minutes, atm can't mark it :(

Comment: @Andreas you are correct, I'm pretty sure that I have not read it thoroughly enough.

Comment: @ArneDB Now you can! :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the bump, I forgot about! Thanks @Rahul